# Recreating setfenv() in Lua 5.2

Tags: lua

How can I recreate the functionality of `setfenv` in Lua 5.2? I'm having some trouble understanding exactly how you are supposed to use the new `_ENV` environment variable.

In Lua 5.1 you can use `setfenv` to sandbox any function quite easily.

```
--# Lua 5.1

print('_G', _G)             -- address of _G

local foo = function()  
    print('env', _G)        -- address of sandbox _G
    bar = 1
end

-- create a simple sandbox
local env = { print = print }
env._G = env

-- set the environment and call the function
setfenv(foo, env)
foo()

-- we should have global in our environment table but not in _G
print(bar, env.bar)
```

Running this example shows an output:

```
_G    table: 0x62d6b0
env   table: 0x635d00
nil   1
```

I would like to recreate this simple example in Lua 5.2. Below is my attempt, but it does not work like the above example.

```
--# Lua 5.2

local function setfenv(f, env)
    local _ENV = env or {}       -- create the _ENV upvalue
    return function(...)
        print('upvalue', _ENV)   -- address of _ENV upvalue
        return f(...)
    end
end

local foo = function()
    print('_ENV', _ENV)          -- address of function _ENV
    bar = 1
end

-- create a simple sandbox
local env = { print = print }
env._G = env

-- set the environment and call the function
foo_env = setfenv(foo, env)
foo_env()

-- we should have global in our envoirnment table but not in _G
print(bar, env.bar)
```

Running this example shows the output:

```
upvalue    table: 0x637e90
_ENV       table: 0x6305f0
1          nil
```

I am aware of several other questions on this subject, but they mostly seem to be dealing with loading dynamic code (files or string) which work quite well using the new `load` function provided in Lua 5.2. Here I am specifically asking for a solution to run arbitrary functions in a sandbox. I would like to do this without using the `debug` library. According to the Lua [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.9) we should not have to rely on it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot change the environment of a function without using the debug library from Lua in Lua 5.2. Once a function has been created, that is the environment it has. The only way to modify this environment is by modifying its first upvalue, which requires the debug library.

The general idea with environments in Lua 5.2 is that the environment should be considered immutable outside of trickery (ie: the debug library). You create a function in an environment; once created there, that's the environment it has. Forever.

This is how environments were often used in Lua 5.1, but it was easy and sanctioned to modify the environment of anything with a casual function call. And if your Lua interpreter removed `setfenv` (to prevent users from breaking the sandbox), then the user code can't set the environment for their own functions internally. So the outside world gets a sandbox, but the inside world can't have a sandbox *within* the sandbox.

The Lua 5.2 mechanism makes it harder to modify the environment post function-creation, but it does allow you to set the environment *during* creation. Which lets you sandbox inside the sandbox.

So what you really want is to just rearrange your code like this:

```
local foo;

do
  local _ENV = { print = print }

  function foo()
    print('env', _ENV)
    bar = 1
  end
end
```

`foo` is now sandboxed. And now, it's much harder for someone to break the sandbox.

As you can imagine, this has caused some contention among Lua developers.

Comment: Lua 5.2 has *lexical* environments, not the magical dynamical ones in Lua 5.1. As mentioned by Nicol, one can still change the  environment of a function by changing an upvalue, if one know where it is.

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit expensive, but if it's that important to you...

Why not use **string.dump**, and re-**load** the function into the right environment?

```
function setfenv(f, env)
    return load(string.dump(f), nil, nil, env)
end
function foo()
    herp(derp)
end

setfenv(foo, {herp = print, derp = "Hello, world!"})()
```

Comment: +1 Until now, my mind has always skipped over string.dump when reading the manual.

Answer (score 12):

To recreate `setfenv/getfenv` in Lua 5.2 you can do the following:

```
if not setfenv then -- Lua 5.2
  -- based on http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-06/msg00314.html
  -- this assumes f is a function
  local function findenv(f)
    local level = 1
    repeat
      local name, value = debug.getupvalue(f, level)
      if name == '_ENV' then return level, value end
      level = level + 1
    until name == nil
    return nil end
  getfenv = function (f) return(select(2, findenv(f)) or _G) end
  setfenv = function (f, t)
    local level = findenv(f)
    if level then debug.setupvalue(f, level, t) end
    return f end
end
```

RPFeltz's answer (`load(string.dump(f)...)`) is a clever one and may work for you, but it doesn't deal with functions that have upvalues (other than _ENV).

There is also [compat-env](https://github.com/davidm/lua-compat-env) module that implements Lua 5.1 functions in Lua 5.2 and vice versa.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it without the debug library, but its nice to see how it should be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In Lua5.2 a sandboxeable function needs to specify that itself. One simple pattern you can use is have it receive `_ENV` as an argument

```
function(_ENV)
    ...
end
```

Or wrap it inside something that defines the env

```
local mk_func(_ENV)
    return function()
        ...
    end
end

local f = mk_func({print = print})
```

However, this explicit use of `_ENV` is less useful for sandboxing, since you can't always assume the other function will cooperate by having an `_ENV` variable. In that case, it depends on what you do. If you just want to load code from some other file then functions such as `load` and `loadfile` usually receive an optional environment parameter that you can use for sandboxing. Additionally, if the code you are trying to load is in string format you can use string manipulation to add `_ENV` variables yourself (say, by wrapping a function with an env parameter around it)

```
local code = 'return function(_ENV) return ' .. their_code .. 'end'
```

Finally, if you really need dynamic function environment manipulation, you can use the debug library to change the function's internal upvalue for `_ENV`. While using the debug library is not usually encouraged, I think it is acceptable if all the other alternatives didn't apply (I feel that in this case changing the function's environment is deep voodoo magic already so using the debug library is not much worse)

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is a nice approach, but it seems it is not possible to sandbox a function I didn't write without the debug library.

Comment: @Adam: Where are you getting these functions from anyway? As I said, you should still be able to sandbox at a module level instead of in a function level.